# Curvature of $\operatorname{SL}(2)$ (manifolds)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, lie-groups, smooth-manifolds, curvature

If we view Lie groups as manifolds, we can pose this question:

> What is the curvature of the unit element of $\operatorname{SL}(2)$?

What I thought:
I know that $\operatorname{SL}(2)=\{M\in L(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R}^2):\det M=1\}$ had unit element $I_2$.
Further if $N:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow S^3$ is a unit normal field, then $\det DN(I_2)$ is the curvature.
So what we are actually looking for is such a unit normal field. What is a good example?

Edit (context of the question):

> A Lie group is a manifold $G$ that is also a group such that the multiplication map and the inversion map are differentiable. Suppose that $G$ is compact, connected and is a $2n$-manifold in a $2n+1$ dimensional vector space.

That is the introduction to the question.

Comment: What metric are you giving?

Comment: @AHusain There is no metric given (does that mean euclidean?)

Comment: @AHusain Could you help me with this question?

Comment: So what do you mean by curvature with no metric?

Comment: @AHusain I think it is assumed here we have the euclidean metric. Does that make it clearer?

Comment: @AHusain My textbook does not specify any metric

Comment: Do you mean induced from inclusion into euclidean R4? You have to specify this map to do the calculation.

Comment: @AHusain Thats what I meant

Comment: @AHusain How would the calculation go then?

Comment: This is a strange question; by "curvature" you mean the determinant of the [Gauss map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_map#Generalizations), viewing $SL(2, \mathbf{R})$ as a smooth hypersurface in flat Euclidean $4$-space? In what context did the question arise...?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I added the context of the question

Comment: So you have your tangent vectors at your point in the embedding and how they appear in the Euclidean space. Same procedure as back when you did surfaces in R3. You can get the induced metric, etc

Comment: @AHusain Could you please show me? I have a hard time understanding what to do

Comment: @DannyRandall can you share your reference?

Comment: @Boris They are lecture notes from my course on manifolds

Comment: can you share them? if you want to @DannyRandall

Answer (score 1):

First lets give a local coordinate patch around the identity so $\alpha \; \beta \; \gamma$ will be coordinates on the embedded $SL(2,R)$ and $a,b,c,d$ on the $\mathbb{R}^4$. These coordinates are defined by computing the formula below. You can make another choice if you want.

\begin{eqnarray*}
X (\alpha, \beta , \gamma ) &=& exp \begin{pmatrix}\alpha&\beta\\
\gamma&-\alpha\\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}X^a&X^b\\
X^c&X^d\\
\end{pmatrix}
\end{eqnarray*}

So the induced metric is now $g_{mn} = \sum_{\mu\nu} \partial_m X^\mu \partial_n X^\nu g_{\mu \nu}$. mn run through a,b,c,d and $\mu,\nu$ through $\alpha \; \beta \; \gamma$. So now compute the $X^{a,b,c,d}$ in terms of $\alpha \; \beta \; \gamma$, take their derivatives and compute the induced metric.

Now you can compute all your Riemann/Ricci curvature tensors in terms of this metric and this coordinate patch and never have to touch the $\mathbb{R}^4$ again. Just plug in this $g_{mn}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the space of $2 \times 2$ real matrices as
$$
\left[\begin{array}{@{}cc@{}}
    a & b \\
    c & d \\
  \end{array}\right]
\leftrightarrow (a, b, c, d),
$$
then $\operatorname{SL}(2)$ is the level set $\det(a, b, c, d) = ad - bc = 1$, the identity matrix corresponds to the point $(1, 0, 0, 1)$, and the gradient of the determinant,
$$
\nabla \det(a, b, c, d) = (d, -c, -b, a),
$$
furnishes a non-vanishing normal field along $\operatorname{SL}(2)$, so you may as well take
$$
N = \frac{(d, -c, -b, a)}{\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} + d^{2}}}.
$$
Alternatively, you could solve for $d$ locally, $d = \frac{1}{a}(1 + bc)$, and proceed using whatever tools you have for working with the curvature of a graph.

---

This addresses the literal question, but may not be substantively helpful, since the notation $N:\mathbf{C} \to S^{3}$ makes one wonder if some surface slice of $\operatorname{SL}(2)$ is to be taken. (If so, that raises other suspicions, since for surfaces in $\mathbf{R}^{4}$, the Gaussian curvature is not the determinant of the Gauss map.)

Separately, the explicit mention of "compact" in the problem introduction is at least mildly perverse, since $\operatorname{SL}(2)$ is a non-compact hyperboloid.

Answer (score 0):

I will treat $M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$ like $\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ in order to obtain an inner product which agrees with the determinant.

Suppose $A, B\in M_{2x2}(\mathbb{R})$  with columns $\{a_1,a_2\}$ and $\{b_1,b_2\}$ respectively.

Let $(A,B)=\frac{1}{2}(\det(a_1,b_2)+\det(b_1,a_2))$

Then $(A,A)=|A|^2:= \det(A)$

and

$(A,B)=(B,A)$

Let $\alpha=\begin{bmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$.

Then $1=\det(\alpha):=|\alpha|^2=(\alpha,\alpha) = \alpha\delta - \beta\gamma$

But $\alpha \delta-\beta \gamma=\frac{1}{4}((\alpha+\delta)^2-(\alpha-\delta)^2-(\beta+\gamma)^2+(\beta-\gamma)^2)=1$

Therefore

$\frac{1}{4}((\alpha+\delta)^2+(\beta-\gamma)^2)=\cosh^2(t)$

$\frac{1}{4}((\alpha-\delta)^2+(\beta+\gamma)^2)=\sinh^2(t)$

So we can write

$\frac{1}{2}(\alpha+\delta)=\cosh(t)\cos(\theta)$

$\frac{1}{2}(\beta-\gamma)=\cosh(t)\sin(\theta)$

$\frac{1}{2}(\alpha-\delta)=\sinh(t)\cos(\phi)$

$\frac{1}{2}(\beta+\gamma)=\sinh(t)\sin(\phi)$

Writing $X(\alpha)=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\delta\\\beta\\\gamma\end{pmatrix}$
Then

$X(t,\theta,\phi)=\begin{pmatrix}\cosh(t)\cos\theta+\sinh(t)\cos\phi\\\cosh(t)\cos\theta-\sinh(t)\cos\phi\\\cosh(t)\sin\theta+\sinh(t)\sin\phi\\-\cosh(t)\sin\theta+\sinh(t)\sin\phi \end{pmatrix}$.

Notice, we need to take dot products to compute stuff so lets figure out what that is. Notice that we can use polarization. (Of course you can compute the metric by expanding dot products in terms of basis vectors and translating back to determinants, but I thought this way was nice)

Let $(\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\delta\\\beta\\\gamma\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\delta\\\beta\\\gamma\end{pmatrix})=\alpha\delta-\gamma\beta$

By definition $(a+b,a+b)=|a|^2+|b|^2+2(a,b)$

$=(\begin{pmatrix}a^1+b^1\\a^2+b^2\\a^3+b^3\\a^4+b^4\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}a^1+b^1\\a^2+b^2\\a^3+b^3\\a^4+b^4\end{pmatrix})=a^1a^2-a^3a^4+b^1b^2-b^3b^4+a^1b^2+a^2b^1-a^3b^4-a^4b^3$

Therefore $(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(a^1b^2+a^2b^1-a^3b^4-a^4b^3)$

I believe you can do the rest on your own. However, I recommend rewriting $X(t,\theta,\phi)$ in terms of the vectors.

$a(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta\\\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}$ and $b(\phi)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos\phi\\-\cos\phi\\\sin\phi\\\sin\phi\end{pmatrix}$

compute $a',b',a'',b''$ and show

$(a,a)=|a|^2=1,|b|^2=-1,|a'|^2=1,|b'|^2=-1 $

and

$(a,b)=0,(a,a')=0,(a,b')=0,(b,a')=0,(b,b')=0, (a',b')=0$

Rewriting $X$ in terms of $a,b$ we get

$X(t,\theta,\phi)=\cosh(t)a(\theta)+\sinh(t)b(\phi)$

We have the coordinate frame

$X_t=\sinh(t)a(\theta)+\cosh(t)b(\phi)$

$X_\theta=\cosh(t)a'(\theta)$

$X_\phi=\sinh(t)b'(\phi)$

Show that $N=X(t,\theta,\phi)$ by taking inner products. From this, we conclude $II=g$

Now you can use the characterization of curvature in terms of the second fundamental form. $R(X,Y,Z,W)= II(X,W)II(Y,Z)-II(X,Z)II(W,Y)$